# Android - "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is android.R.id.list"

Tags: android, android-activity, listactivity

I browsed through every other same/similar question:

[Android: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is android.R.id.list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647831/android-your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-li)

[Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050817/your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list)

None of it helped.

The difference is that my Activity doesn't extend ListActivitiy (which seemed to be the problem in the above cases).

My activity extends FragmentActivity (and I can't really change this to Activity because I have dependencies).

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

...
ListView

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" >
</ListView>
```

... Fragment view.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/contentFragment"
    android:name="com.landa.fragment.ContentFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include1" />
```

I also tried changing the 'id' format of the ListView as suggested in the above questions - Android doesn't agree with that notation.

Content fragment extends ListFragment:

```
public class ContentFragment extends ListFragment {
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: And where is the `ListView`?

Comment: One second, just adding the code.

Comment: Is the fragment a `ListFragment`? Where exactly is the ListView? Part of which layout in which UI component?

Comment: Yes. "public class ContentFragment extends ListFragment " it's a ListFragment. ListView is inside content_view.xml.  It's rendered in the fragment with "return inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_view, container, false);". I'll add the full code now.

Comment: By the way, my code works when I do not extend the fragment with ListFragment. But then my list renders as one big object and I can't click it's elements.

Comment: Are you're sure you did `<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"`? That should work I'd say.

Comment: Yes, that produces an error on the following line: "ListView list = (ListView) ac.findViewById(R.id.list);" where "ac" is an Activity (extended FragmentActivity)

Comment: You have to work with the fragment's view. and when you're finding the Id, use `android.R.id.list` (or in the fragment `getListView()` However, why not let the fragment handle the list itself? Then have optional callbacks to the Activity.

Comment: This fixed the problem. Answer the question and I'll accept. But there's one last problem I have - I can't scroll through elements of my list (vertical list) - any idea why?

Comment: Answer posted! Also, since your new issue is different than what this question asks, you should make a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First problem:

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

needed to be

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Then when you want to access the `ListView`, you can do it in this way if you're working in your Activity and you have a reference to the Fragment:

```
ListView l = fragment.getListView();
```

or

```
ListView l = (ListView) fragment.getView().findViewById (android.R.id.list);
```

If you're in the fragment, calling `getListView()` will suffice.

Also don't forget that you can have `Fragment -> Activity` communication by always casting `getActivity()` into `YourActivity` to call your logic methods or by creating an interface to handle this.